# Como obtener la referencia del elemento que evalua un disabled

Tags: angular

Tengo una funcion que habilita o des-habilita un button, el problema es que a ese button depende si se des-habilita o no le quiero agregar un tooltip y para eso necesito la referencia del button,
Funcion:

```
employeeHaveThisPermission(accion: number, buttonRef: HTMLElement): boolean {
 const canDoit = this.authService.canDoThisAccion(accion);
 if (!canDoit) {
  console.log(buttonRef);
  buttonRef.setAttribute('title', 'No cuenta con los permisos necesarios para esta acción');
 }

 return canDoit;
}
```

En front.

```
<button type="button" #btnClose  class="btn btn-success" (click)="closeShift()"
    [disabled]="!employeeHaveThisPermission(specialPermissionsEnum.CloseShift, btnClose)">
    Cerrar Turno {{btnCloseShift.value}}
  </button>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que eh intentado pero en la funcion me llega "undefined" en el parametro de buttonRef

Answer (score 0):

`tooltip` no es una propiedad `html` valida. Puedes usar `title` y funciona correctamente. Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kccydx) aquí.

#### El código de tu componente quedaría de esta manera:

---

```js
employeeHaveThisPermission(accion: number, buttonRef: HTMLElement): boolean {
 const canDoit = this.cerrar
 if (!canDoit) {
    console.log(buttonRef);
    buttonRef.setAttribute('title', 'No cuenta con los permisos necesarios para esta acción');
 } else {
    buttonRef.setAttribute('title', 'Si puede cerrar');

 }

 return canDoit;
}
```

Comment: El problema es que no puedo obtener la referencia del elemento en la función. me llega como undefined

Comment: `#btnClose` es lo que no te llega?

Comment: Exacto, cuando lo envio desde el evento OnClick, si me llega la referencia, pero en el [Disabled] no, llega como undefined

Comment: tambien me pudiera servir, guardar la respuesta de esa funcion en una variable declarada en el html, asi pudiera hacer tipo : 
<button [title]='canDoit?'':'No cuenta con permisos''; [disabled]='canDoit' >
No quiero declarar una variable en el ts, debido a que tengo multiples permisos y tendrai que crear una variable por cada permiso

Comment: Es otra opción valida.

Comment: Se puede declarar una variable en el html que viva solo dentro de un div?

Comment: La puedes declarar en tu componente y luego utilizar `ngModel` para obtener su resultado. Revisa el ejemplo en stackblitz, el input utiilza esa forma.